# UI-Select On-select callback being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select. And there is requirement to call some method on on-select of an item.
Here is my code

```
 <ui-select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedPersonId" 
         theme="bootstrap"  close-on-select="true"  
         title="Search Person by Id"
         name="personSearch" 
         on-select="myCtrl.onPersonSelect()">
     <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Search Person">
         {{$select.selected.name}}
     </ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="item.id as item in myCtrl.personsResult" 
             refresh="myCtrl.personSearch()"
             minimum-input-length="1" 
             refresh-delay="1000">
         <div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div>
         <small>
             name: {{item.name}}
         </small>
     </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

The problem is that the callback method `on-select="myCtrl.onPersonSelect()"` is being called mutiple times. When user selects an item, then it is called and also when user click on ui-select and the input box appears to type result, then also it is called. So for one selection it gets called 2-3 times. whenever user clicks on input, on-select function gets called.

This might be because of result data getting from $http.

Can somebody help me in this.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle..because your code looks fine